# Eclipse workspace corrupts on every single close

Tags: java, eclipse, crash

**Every single time I close Eclipse**, the workspace corrupts. The only thing that I can do to get back into the workspace is delete the .metadata folder, but after I do that I have to re-import all my projects. Switching the workspace to another folder doesn't work, as that one corrupts the second time I open it as well. The problem isn't due to improper shutdown (as far as I know) because I have been closing it (and in some cases doing file > restart). I should also mention that eclipse was working fine the other day but no longer works.

The error log can be located at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0MczP7mf)

Sorry if the solution is obvious, but I'm new to eclipse.

I am running Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Luna SR2 (4.4.2) and Windows 8 x64.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the log look when you close Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird errors like ClassFormatError mean the class file isn't right for the jdk that is trying to run it.  Did your JDK get updated to a newer version recently?  This class file is part of your Eclipse Modeling Framework plugin, and you are running on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45.

Three things I can think of that you can try.

1. Check update manager and see if there are updates to the Eclipse Modeling Framework plugin.
2. Upgrade Eclipse to the latest version of Luna 4.4.2.  I know that version supports Java 8.
3. Try running Eclipse with an earlier version of the JDK.

Comment: Upgrading my Eclipse and downgrading my JDK fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pls can u try using any other JDK compiler other than 1.8 like 1.7 pr 1.6

to me this appears to be compiler related issue

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .metadata does not necessarily repair a corrupt workspace.

Instead you should try to clean it:

1. Right-click on the shortcut to Eclipse and say "properties
2. `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe" -clean` (change your path accordingly to your system)